# Pandas: Merge two dataframe columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge

Consider two dataframes:

```
df_a = pd.DataFrame([
        ['a', 1],
        ['b', 2],
        ['c', NaN],
    ], columns=['name', 'value'])

df_b = pd.DataFrame([
        ['a', 1],
        ['b', NaN],
        ['c', 3],
        ['d', 4]
    ], columns=['name', 'value'])
```

So looking like

```
# df_a
  name  value
0   a   1
1   b   2
2   c   NaN

# df_b
  name  value
0   a   1
1   b   NaN
2   c   3
3   d   4
```

I want to merge these two dataframes and fill in the NaN values of the `value` column with the existing values in the other column. In other words, I want out:

```
# DESIRED RESULT
  name  value
0   a   1
1   b   2
2   c   3
3   d   4
```

Sure, I can do this with a custom `.map` or `.apply`, but I want a solution that uses `merge` or the like, not writing a custom merge function. How can this be done?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you can use [`combine_first`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.combine_first.html):

```
print (df_b.combine_first(df_a))
  name  value
0    a    1.0
1    b    2.0
2    c    3.0
3    d    4.0
```

Or [`fillna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html):

```
print (df_b.fillna(df_a))
  name  value
0    a    1.0
1    b    2.0
2    c    3.0
3    d    4.0
```

Solution with [`update`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.update.html) is not so common as `combine_first`:

```
df_b.update(df_a)
print (df_b)
  name  value
0    a    1.0
1    b    2.0
2    c    3.0
3    d    4.0
```

Comment: `combine_first` works great! Thanks.

However, `fillna` & `update` do not work to do an outer join - both will only fill values that exist in the calling dataframe. For instance, df_a.fillna(df_b) obliviates the `d` row. Same with `update`. They aren't a general solution, unless you can make certain assumptions about your data.